# How to add multiple safe addresses in outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

i have created a outlook macro where if i want to send email other then the listed email id,it will give me a popup. However, i am not being able to add multiple email ids to the list. please find the below code that i have written. Can someone please help me how to add multiple email ids in my below code?

```html
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Const ADDR_TO_WATCH_FOR = "James.t@outlook.com"
    
    Dim olkRec As Outlook.Recipient
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        For Each olkRec In Item.Recipients
            If LCase(olkRec.Address) <> ADDR_TO_WATCH_FOR Then
       If MsgBox("This message is addressed to " & ADDR_TO_WATCH_FOR & ".  Are you sure you want to send it?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Confirm Send") = vbNo Then
        
                    Cancel = True
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Set olkRec = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't show the message box inside the loop over all recipients. Run the loop first and check all recipients. Build a list of multiple recipients if necessary. After you exit the loop, check if that list (a string) if not empty, show the message box.

Comment: Is it possible to build a list of multiple recipients in excel and link the same in Outlook macro ?

Comment: I am not being able to build a list of multiple recipients in Outlook macro. Could you please help me on this ?

Comment: Why do you need Excel for that? Declare a string, inside your loop over the recipients, append the address to that string if the address matches. When the loop exits, you will have matching addresses concatenated to a string.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But my recipients list keep on changing day by day and I don't want to update Outlook macro for the same on a daily basis. Instead I am comfortable to update a excel sheet and outlook macro import the recipient list from that excel. But I am not being able to link outlook macro with that excel. Could you please help me on this ?

Comment: Your macro would need to open the Excel spreadsheet and read the data from it. But that is really an Excel question, not Outlook.